# Is a question a duplicate when it has the same answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This question: [Assign variable content to object property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003760/assign-variable-content-to-object-property-name) was just marked as a duplicate of [How do I add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

The first question is about creating an object literal with dynamic properties in node, and the second is about assigning a value to a dynamic property of an existing object in a browser.

They're obviously similar, and the answers are nearly identical..., but are they duplicates? Would a person looking for an answer to the first question realize that the second question would have isomorphic solutions?

Comment: *"Would a person looking for an answer to the first question realize that the second question would have isomorphic solutions?"* Why would that matter? Someone else has realized that for them and marked the question as a duplicate. Assuming the answers are actually the same, the person who asked the question and anyone else who comes across it in the future will have the solution.

Comment: @CodyGray in this case it might matter because the second question contains jquery/dom that is unrelated to the question asked that needs to be parsed and found irrelevant by a human reader (not to mention undeclared variables, but I digress) - unless you assume people would go directly to the answers?

Comment: Well yeah, if I'm told "the answer to your question is over here," I'd start by looking at the answer. I might glance at the question, but I'd really only scrutinize it if the answer didn't make sense on its own. More generally, I don't think the questions have to be carbon-copies of each other to be duplicates. The whole reason for making a question as a duplicate is to avoid unnecessary duplication of answers. Everyone has slightly different code.